# Passing variables with metacharacters through preg_match?

Tags: php, preg-match, backslash

I've been trying for three hours to pass these variables(strings)
through preg_match. i have tried everything. preg_quote just messes them up worse.

```
".html">";

"</a> (<a";
```

you'd think that

```
"/.html/">";   and

"</a> /(<a"; would work but no
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php), and set the second parameter to be your regex delimiter.

Comment: doesn't work. i can pass "=t\">" and "</a>)</font>" as variables no problem, but nothing else. i'm going to rip off my face

Comment: @Graham you can use back ticks (`) to format code in comments just as you can in questions.

Comment: i can pass http:// but not "http:// or http://rad or http://rad. i'm still trying to solve this ridiculous discrimination principle of preg_match

Comment: @Graham: The answer answers that already. Just read it for once.

Comment: answer? where? I'm concluding i've tapped into some arbitrary demonic possession of the function - It accepts HTTP but not HREF, and, you wouldn't believe the maddening assortment of illogical bits of the code/text this function will and will not accept. this is the most confounding thing I've ever experienced. let's have a look at this function at last: `function retrieveBetween($subject, $start, $end) {
  $matchPattern = "#$start(.*)$end#";
  if (preg_match_all($matchPattern, $subject, $matches)) {
   return $matches[1];
  } else {
   return "Could not find valid match.";
  }
 }

Comment: @Graham format your code in comments! Looks like you might have missed the closing back tick.

Comment: `function retrieveBetween($subject, $start, $end) {
  $matchPattern = "#$start(.*)$end#";
  if (preg_match_all($matchPattern, $subject, $matches)) {
   return $matches[1];
  } else {
   return "Could not find valid match.";
  }
 }
`

Comment: backticks either side. didn't work. it's 7am in New York City. I'm quit!

Comment: SOLVED!!! preg_match_all was failing ONLY if the string which it found between the variable delimiters contained a blank space or a period. Took six hours to figure that out.

Comment: UNSOLVED!!! Knowing the above helped nothing. There is no way to strip periods and whitespace from HTML in a string. strpos, preg_replace, trim. Spaces remain. I need the HTML tags as reference points to pull out the actual text. But, unfortunately using preg_match_all, or anything else for that matter, I can't even locate them. I've wasted 9 hours trying to figure out how to extract a list of names from an html page. Must be some kind of specially coded HTML page.

Comment: I think we are all getting confused here. Could you edit your question and post: the code you are using now, the actual output, and the expected output. Echo out some preg_quote statements and tell us exactly what you're expecting to get back. Additionally, maybe this issue is a regex issue and not a preg_quote issue, so explain what you're trying to achieve.